# Giving java program access to ArcGIS Network Analyst calculations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, java, network-analyst

I have a fire department simulator written in Java that simulates a year of fire department responses.  There is a Java method/function that calculates time between two coordinates using a fairly simple equation that assumes a gridded street system.

I am trying to improve the simulation results by figuring out a way in which the Java program could pass out start/end coordinates and have ArcGIS / Network Analyst calculate and return the drive time required.

Is there any way to build this interaction between a Java program and ArcGIS for Desktop (or Server)?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS for Desktop or Server?

Comment: ArcGIS Desktop ... but I would also be interested to know if there is a ArcGIS Server solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way to do this would be to write your Java program to call a Python script that returns the drive time value that you seek.

The Python script would need to import ArcPy and use its Network Analyst (arcpy.na) module.

If you need help with the Java program then Stack Overflow would be the place to seek it.

If you need help with ArcPy then post a question with code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck on this site.